# Regular abelian groups of order $2^m$ and type $(2,2,\ldots,2)$

Tags: permutations

I was wondering if there is a systematic way to construct the regular Abelian groups of order $2^m$ and type $(2,2,\ldots,2)$.  Since the permutation group needs to be regular, it should act transitively on a set of size $2^m$.  For example, if $m=2$, the unique regular permutation group of order 4 and type $C_2 \times C_2$ is $\{1, (12)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)\}$.

How about a permutation group $G \le S_8$ of order 8, acting regularly on $\{1,\ldots,8\}$, isomorphic to $C_2^3$?  Since $G$ is semiregular, every one of the 7 nonidentity permutations has no fixed points.  Since each of these permutations must have order 2, each is a product of exactly 4 transpositions.  Thus, the ${8 \choose 2}=28$ transpositions need to be partitioned into 7 subsets, each containing 4 transpositions, such that we have an Abelian group structure.  Is there a systematic way to do this?

Actually, the context of my question is as follows.  [Wielandt, *Finite Permutation Groups*, Section 13] mentions in his text the following assertion:  Let $G$ be primitive on $\Omega$ and $G_\Delta$ transitive on $\Omega-\Delta=\Gamma$, $1 < |\Gamma| \le \frac{1}{2}|\Omega|$; then, $|\Gamma| < \frac{1}{2}|\Omega|$ implies $G$ is alternating or symmetric.

The text then says that the hypothesis $|\Gamma| < \frac{1}{2}|\Omega|$ may be omitted in the assertion unless $|\Omega|=2^m, m \ge 3$, and that in this exceptional case a counterexample is provided by the normalizer, in $S^\Omega$, of the regular Abelian group of order $2^m$ and type $(2,2,\ldots,2)$.  So, I was wondering what these regular Abelian groups look like, what their normalizers would be, and why they provide a counterexample.

Comment: I find the formulation of the question somewhat confusing. I think that you are asking for finding certain _subgroups_ of the symmetric group on $2^n$ points that are isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^n$, which is not the same are constructing/counting _groups_ (I think there is up to isomorphism only one group involved, though I might be wrong). At least you could mention permutation groups instead of groups.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: yes, that's what I meant - permutation groups that are subgroups of $S_{2^n}$ and isomorphic to $C_2^n$. I think the word ``regular'' makes it clear it's a permutation group, and I used the tag on permutation groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked the details but there are some suggestive patterns

$(12)(34)(56)(78)$

$(13)(24)(57)(68)$

$(14)(23)(58)(67)$

$(15)(26)(37)(48)$

$(16)(25)(38)(47)$

$(17)(28)(35)(46)$

$(18)(27)(36)(45)$

$1$ pairs with $2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ which is the organising scheme, together with including the four-group at the beginning

$2$ pairs with $1,4,3,6,5,8,7$

$3$ pairs with $4,1,2,7,8,5,6$

$4$ pairs with $3,2,1,8,7,6,5$

$5$ pairs with $6,7,8,1,2,3,4$

$6$ pairs with $5,8,7,2,1,4,3$

$7$ pairs with $8,5,6,3,4,1,2$

$8$ pairs with $7,6,5,4,3,2,1$

The patterns for $1,2,4,8$ could be continued in the next iteration for $16$, and the pattern for $5$ looks as though it could be carried over to $9$ in the next iteration. I am sure there is a simple way of describing this - others may have it to hand.

---

Further to the comment, if the first column is $i$ pairs with $i$ - the identity - and we start with the trivial group, we have the squares

$2^0$

$1$

We replace $n$ by the block

$2n-1, 2n$

$2n, 2n-1$

We get successively - order 2

$1,2$

$2,1$

Then - order 4

$1,2,3,4$

$2,1,4,3$

$3,4,1,2$

$4,3,2,1$

Then order $8$ as above. The squares are symmetric, and we can read the permutations vertically or horizontally.

There are lots of constructions like this for square objects $2^n \times 2^n$ - this must be related to something else.

Comment: If you omit the "pairs with" part you find that $1,2; 3,4; 5,6; 7,8$ come in $2\times 2$ blocks - it looks as though replacing $1$ with a block $1,2$, $2$ with $3,4$ etc will generate a set of permutations for $16$